# Pygame Uservent Object not showing on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to create a Frog game where a frog will have to dodge cars while moving through roads.
I made an user event of car1 which would produce a car after a delay of three seconds. But for some reason it is not being shown on the screen.

I also wanted to know whether how to create multiple car objects moving from left to right, should i store them in variables or is there some other method?

````
import random
import time
# Initialising the program
pygame.init()
# Creating the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
playerImg = pygame.image.load('images/golden-frog.png')
playerX = 330
playerY = 700
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 0
cars = {
    1: pygame.image.load('images/police.png'),
    2: pygame.image.load('images/motorcycle.png'),
    3: pygame.image.load('images/sports1.png')
}
road = pygame.image.load('images/road.png')
def car(a,x,y):
    screen.blit(cars.get(a),(x,y))
def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg,(x,y))
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(road,(0,100))

    a = random.randint(1,len(cars.keys()))
    car1 = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(car1, 3000)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == car1:

            car(1,0,120)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 30
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -30
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 50
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -50
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or  event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY_change = 0
    playerX += playerX_change
    playerY += playerY_change
    if playerX < 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX > 674:
        playerX = 674
    if playerY < 0:
        playerY = 0
    if playerY > 674:
        playerY = 674
    player(playerX,playerY)
    clock.tick(11)
    pygame.display.update()```
````

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of your game loop, you are calling `pygame.time.set_timer()`. Calling [set_timer()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) discards the old timer for this event, so your `car1` timer will never trigger.

Move the call to `set_timer` before your `while` statement.

Note also that your `car1` event handler will be triggered after three seconds and will blit your car surface to your screen. You'll be able to see the image for one eleventh of a second before your game loop runs again and the background draws over your car. You could do something similar to your `player` function which is called every loop. Longer term you should investigate [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).